# Aggregation based on previous month from eventdate

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I'm Stuck on a problem it would be great if you could help me :)
I created a dataframe with pandas:
looks like that:

| HostName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 12:30 |
| B | 2021-01-01 12:42 |
| B | 2021-02-01 12:30 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:40 |
| A | 2021-02-25 12:40 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:41 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:42 |

I try to Aggregat based on the previous month but it's not working.
the end result should look like this:

| HostName | Date | previous month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 12:30 | Nan |
| B | 2021-01-01 12:42 | Nan |
| B | 2021-02-01 12:30 | 1 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:40 | Nan |
| A | 2021-02-25 12:40 | 1 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:41 | 2 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:42 | 3 |

for every row Date should look one-month before and Aggregat the number of Hostnames found.
for example row number 6 count HostName A from 2021-02-01 12:41 to 2021-03-01 12:41

what I try to do and failed:

1. extract the previous month:

```
 df['Date Before'] = df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

2. and Aggregate between this month

```
 df.resample('M', on='Date').HostName.count()
 df.groupby('HostName').resample('M', on='Date Before').HostName.count()
```

Please Help Me many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

use shift to look back a n rows for a dataframe column. df is the group by results.

```
 data1="""HostName  Date
A   2021-01-01 12:30
B   2021-01-01 12:42
B   2021-02-01 12:30
A   2021-02-01 12:40
A   2021-02-25 12:40
A   2021-03-01 12:41
A   2021-03-01 12:42"""
    
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data1), sep='\t')    
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

grouped=df.groupby('HostName')['Date']

def previous_date(group):
    return group.sort_values().shift(1)

df['Previous Date']=grouped.apply(previous_date)

df['Previous Count']=df.apply(lambda x: x['Date']-x['Previous Date'],axis=1)

print(df.sort_values(by=["HostName","Date"]))


df['Con'] = np.where( (df['Previous Date'].notnull() & df['Previous Count']>0) , 1, 0)

print(df.sort_values(by=["HostName","Date"]))
```

output:

```
     HostName                Date       Previous Date  Previous Count  Con
0        A 2021-01-01 12:30:00                 NaT             NaN    0
3        A 2021-02-01 12:40:00 2021-01-01 12:30:00            31.0    1
4        A 2021-02-25 12:40:00 2021-02-01 12:40:00            24.0    1
5        A 2021-03-01 12:41:00 2021-02-25 12:40:00             4.0    1
6        A 2021-03-01 12:42:00 2021-03-01 12:41:00             0.0    0
1        B 2021-01-01 12:42:00                 NaT             NaN    0
2        B 2021-02-01 12:30:00 2021-01-01 12:42:00            30.0    1
```

use cumsum to create a running total by hostname
​

Comment: its great but "Previous Count" should count the number of times Hostname found not days for example index 3 column  "Previous Count" should get 0

Comment: you can use the dataframe transform and look back from the current row to the beginning or a hostname change and count where days = 0

Comment: Yes I know but the results would be for index 0,3,4,5,6 - 5 and for index 1,2 - 2 but this is not the case because it should count A only if A found in the real month before the Date for example index 4 the date is 2021-02-25 12:40:00 so a the real month before is 2021-01-25 12:40:00 so it's 2 because A found in 2021-02-25 12:40:00 and 2021-02-01 12:40:00 but not 2021-01-01 12:30:00 because its more then month before

Answer (score 0):

i found solution:
original:

```
HostName    Date
0   A   2021-01-01 12:30:00
1   B   2021-01-01 12:42:00
2   B   2021-02-01 12:30:00
3   A   2021-02-01 12:40:00
4   A   2021-02-25 12:40:00
5   A   2021-03-01 12:41:00
6   A   2021-03-01 12:42:00
```

get month before

```
df['Month Before'] = df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

order datafarme

```
df = df.sort_values(['HostName','Date'])
```

shift by Host

```
df['prev_value'] = df.groupby('HostName')['Date'].shift()
```

checking

```
df['Con'] = np.where((df['Month Before'] <= df['prev_value']) | (df['prev_value'].notnull()) , 1, 0)
```

and group

```
gpc = df.groupby(['HostName','Con'])['HostName']
df['Count Per Host'] = gpc.cumcount()
```

look like that

```
    HostName    Date    Month Before                 prev_value        Con   CountPerHost
0   A   2021-01-01 12:30:00 2020-12-01 12:30:00     NaT                 0      0
3   A   2021-02-01 12:40:00 2021-01-01 12:40:00 2021-01-01 12:30:00     0      0
4   A   2021-02-25 12:40:00 2021-01-25 12:40:00 2021-02-01 12:40:00     1      1
5   A   2021-03-01 12:41:00 2021-02-01 12:41:00 2021-02-25 12:40:00     1      2
6   A   2021-03-01 12:42:00 2021-02-01 12:42:00 2021-03-01 12:41:00     1      3
1   B   2021-01-01 12:42:00 2020-12-01 12:42:00     NaT                 0      0
2   B   2021-02-01 12:30:00 2021-01-01 12:30:00 2021-01-01 12:42:00     1     0
```